# How do i add an Object to end of an array in javascript. array.push seams not working for object here

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
let address_book = [];
    function myFunction() {
        let contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone;
        contact_name = document.getElementById("contact_name").value;
        contact_email = document.getElementById("contact_email").value;
        contact_phone = document.getElementById("contact_phone").value;

        address_book.push({
            name: contact_name,
            email: contact_email,
            phone: contact_phone
        })
            alert(address_book)
            console.log(tempObj)
    }

</script>
```

it works if i push any of the input to the array, but not working when i push the object

Comment: And how it's not working? You are logging `tempObj` that is not present in code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qpvz45L8/2/ shows, that it should word, if you assign tempObj correctly.

Comment: `it doesnt work` is not a proper error description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like below:

```
let address_book = [];
    function myFunction() {

        var tempObj = {};
        tempObj.contact_name = document.getElementById("contact_name").value;
        tempObj.contact_email = document.getElementById("contact_email").value;
        tempObj.contact_phone = document.getElementById("contact_phone").value;

        address_book.push(tempObj)
        console.log(tempObj)
    }
            alert(address_book)

</script>
```

**Explanation**:

You were not creating any object to push into the array. First you need to create a `tempObj` every time you want to push a new object into your `address_book`. Above code will perfectly fine.

Comment: @Awwal, that is great. It helped you.

Comment: @Awwal please upvote and accept my answer so that it will be helpful for others as well.

Comment: @Awwal thanks. Did you upvote as well? If not please do so as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code has some problems:

1. You aren't calling the function.
2. `address_book.push` is working, but transforming objects to strings result in something like `[object Object]`. If you want a representation of the object use something like `alert(JSON.stringify(address_book))`.
3. `tempObj` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks! i realized i can't alert an array. that was why i was getting [object Object]

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to accept this answer if you found it useful by clicking the green thing next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
var address_book = [];
var i = 0;

function myFunction() {
        let contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone;
        contact_name = document.getElementById("contact_name").value;
        contact_email = document.getElementById("contact_email").value;
        contact_phone = document.getElementById("contact_phone").value;
        var user = {
            name: contact_name,
            email: contact_email,
            phone: contact_phone
        }
        address_book[i] = user;
        i++;
            alert(address_book)
    }
```